# memory upgrade for Gateway GT-5428

Tags: memory-card

My Gateway GT5428 has (2) 512 PC2-5300u-555-12 memory boards installed from the factory. Iwant to upgrade to 2gb. Will (2) 1gb pc2-5300 ddr2-667 240pin dimm standard non-ecc work for this upgrade or should I go to a PC2-4200 series?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to need two 1GB DIMMs.  Kingston and [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/Gateway-memory/GT+Series/GT5428-upgrades.html) agree on this.  So remove and replace for both factory installed DIMMs